# How do I go into firebase and get my image url and then decode it into a UIImage and then display the picture as a marker Icon in google maps?

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimageview

My code: [the following is my code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS9hX.png)

```
       func queryImageWithCompletion(completion:((image:UIImage?)->Void)?) {
            self.ref.child("users").child((userID)!).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                if let strUrl = snapshot.value as? String, url = NSURL(string: strUrl) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
                        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), image = UIImage(data:data) {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                completion?(image:image)
                                marker.icon = UIImage(data: data)
                            })
                        } else {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                completion?(image:nil)
                            })
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        completion?(image:nil)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
```

that is the code I am using to try to display the picture as a marker icon! Can anyone help me. I am not getting any errors but it won't work.

Comment: Please post your code, not a screenshot of it.  And explain what your error or problem is

Answer (score 1):

Since network operations are asynchronous, I suggest you use the following:

```
func queryImageWithCompletion(completion:((image:UIImage?)->Void)?) {
    ref.child("users").child(String(authorId)).child("profileUrl").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let strUrl = snapshot.value as? String, url = NSURL(string: strUrl) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { 
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), image = UIImage(data:data) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                        completion?(image:image)
                    })
                } else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        completion?(image:nil)
                    })
                }
            })
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                completion?(image:nil)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help? I am using google maps and would like to display that user profile picture as a marker icon. Currently I am trying to do it like this :

Comment: i am setting the marker icon equal to the image under the if let data statement like this: marker.icon = UIImage(data: data)

Comment: Its up in the post. I edited my firsr question with a new one. But my question is how I would display amarker icon as a users profile picture. i already have the picture stored as an image url